# Angular template routing doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'd like to load a template html in my main index.html when I view my angular project but I always get an empty screen.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="nl" ng-app="store">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>NMDAD-II Web App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body class="bg-darkRed" ng-controller="StoreController as store">

<div ng-view></div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.28//angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
<script src="app/app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    angular.module("store", ["ngRoute"])
            .config(function($routeProvider){
                $routeProvider
                        .when('/', {
                            templateUrl: 'app/home/home.view.html'
                        })
                        .otherwise({
                            redirectTo: '/'
                        });
            });

</script>


<script id="__bs_script__">//<![CDATA[
document.write("<script async src='http://HOST:3000/browser-sync/browser-sync-client.2.11.2.js'><\/script>".replace("HOST", location.hostname));
//]]></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I've also tried to load it with browser sync but it's still the same. I want to load home.view.html in my index.html. I tried to write the javascript in app.js but that still didn't work.

EDIT: this is my app.js. my main.js just contains some jquery

```
function () {


    'use strict';

    // Module declarations
    angular.module('store', [
        // Angular Module Dependencies
        // ---------------------------
        'ngAnimate',
        'ngMaterial',
        'ngMessages',
        'ngResource',


        // Third-party Module Dependencies
        // -------------------------------
        'ui.router', // Angular UI Router: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki

        // Custom Module Dependencies
        // --------------------------
        'store.home',
        'store.services'
    ]);
    angular.module('store.home', []);
    angular.module('store.services', []);

    // Make wrapper services and remove globals for Third-party Libraries
    angular.module('store')
        .run(Run);


    function Run(
        $_,
        $faker
    ) {}



    var app = angular.module('store',[]);

    app.controller('StoreController', function(){
        this.products = gems;
    });

  var gems = [
      {
          title: "Islay Blended Malt",
          description: "The Isle of Islay is known for its peaty whiskies. For there is a great abundance of peat on the island, and because electricity reached Islay so late, peated was relied upon as a staple source of fuel. But there is so much than just peat to be found.",
          price: "103.45",
          canPurchase: true

      },

      {
          title: "Springbank 10 Year old",
          description: "Blended from a mixture of bourbon and sherry casks, the light colour of this malt belies the richness of its character.",
          price: "36.25",
          canPurchase: true

      },

      {
          title: "Hazelburn 10 Year old",
          description: "First released in 2014, this is the first bottling of Hazelburn at 10 years of age. Hazelburn is Springbank's triple-distilled, unpeated single malt.",
          price: "37.75",
          canPurchase: true

      }
  ]

})();
```

Comment: any errors in the browser console?

Comment: what `main.js` & `app.js` contains ?

Comment: My console says this:

angular.min.js:117 Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.5/ng/areq?p0=StoreController&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
    at Error (native)
    at http://localhost:3000/vendor/angular/angular.min.js:6:412
    at qb (http://localhost:3000/vendor/angular/angular.min.js:23:157)
    at Pa (http://localhost:3000/vendor/angular/angular.min.js:23:244)
    at http://localhost:3000/vendor/angular/angular.min.js:89:77
    at O (http://localhost:3000/vendor/angular/angular.min.js:72:75)
and so on....

Answer (score 1):

The problem I see is you are loading angular-route before you load angular.

Try switching those two lines to:

```
<script src="vendor/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.28//angular-route.min.js"></script>
```

I get this error `ReferenceError: angular is not defined` when I load the scripts how you are loading them.

Comment: If you remove the `.min` from the angular source path it will give you a more specific error message. It could possible be the path `vendor/angular/angular.min.js` does not exist.